# react native add parent component to every other occurrence

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a question and related 4 answers that needs to be displayed.

The first 2 answer options should be displayed adjacent in one row and next 2 answer options should be displayed in next row.

so, I need a  component start with first occurrence and end  after the 2nd occurrence.

```
<View>
    <answer-1>
    <answer-2>
</View>
```

similarly  should start with 3rd occurrence and end  after 4th occurrence.

```
<View>
    <answer-3>
    <answer-4>
</View>


return (
        <View style={globalStyles.homepagecontainer}>
            <Text>{question}</Text>                                                                            
            {answers.map((a, key)=> {                                                        
                console.log('a - ', a)    
                console.log('key - ', key)    
                const cssstyles1 = {
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row'}
                const cssstyles2 = {
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: colors[key],
                    marginBottom:10,
                    justifyContent: 'center',        
                    flexDirection: 'column'}
                if ( key == 0 || key == 1 ){
                    
                return (
                        <View style={cssstyles1}>
                            <View style={cssstyles2}>
                                <Text>{a}</Text>
                            </View>

                    )   
                }else{
                    return (
                        <View style={cssstyles1}>
                            <View style={cssstyles2}>
                                <Text>{a}</Text>
                            </View>

                    )   
                }
                }
            )}
            <Text>{result}</Text>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember that React code is just that - code.

You can always reorganize your code in more intuitive ways, such as splitting your list of answers into a bidimensional array, and then looping over it.